# Clean install of Apache redirects domain to https

Tags: apache

I've just done a clean install of my server, and installed apache and PHP. I've adapted the default apache virtual hosts file to target the necessary folder and enabled the site, but for some reason when I attempt to access the page in a browser it attempts to reach https://example.com/ instead of http://example.com/

This is newly installed apache server so I have no clue why it would try and use SSL, and as far as I can tell my DNS settings for the domain are correct and I can't see any redirects to https

Comment: 1) Perhaps your domain is on [Chromium HSTS preloaded list](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/net/http/transport_security_state_static.json)

Comment: 2) Perhaps redirection is configured in .htaccess file

Comment: Indeed it is in the HSTS list, is there any way to remove it from there?

Comment: You might be able to do this, but it would probably take several months, and still with uncertain outcome. You should either configure your site to work with https or use another domain.

Comment: @DusanBajic copying in from the last comment and also this one. I also have a domain not on that list, that is doing the same thing. I also don't have a .htaccess file setup yet so it couldn't be that

Comment: Can you share the real domain name?

Comment: @DusanBajic [This is it](http://hardline-dev.xyz/)

Comment: Well, it is not redirecting me to https://, it just opens (plain http) Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page

Comment: @DusanBajic [This](http://puu.sh/pXTkY.png) is what I get, even when using a device that hasn't connected to it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116993/discussion-between-dusan-bajic-and-hardline-98).